# Pandas new cumulating column based on percentange change and initial value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having an initial dataframe like this, defined with a items columns and a percentage column:
[image]

How can I calculate the new items column as shown in the following picture?
[image]

In theory this seems an easy task in my mind (and in Excel/Google Sheet), but trying to do this with a pandas dataframe is getting me mad!
Thank you for the help!

Comment: please provide your data in a reproducible format, not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute the cumulated percentage by dividing by 100, adding 1 and computing the [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html), then multiply by "items":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': list('ABCDE'),
                   'items': 5,
                   'perc': [float('nan'), 0, 24.32, -19.57, -91.80]})

df['new_items'] = (df['perc']
                   .fillna(0).div(100).add(1)
                   .cumprod().mul(df['items'])
                  )
```

Output:

```
  label  items   perc  new_items
0     A      5    NaN   5.000000
1     B      5   0.00   5.000000
2     C      5  24.32   6.216000
3     D      5 -19.57   4.999529
4     E      5 -91.80   0.409961
```

Intermediates:

```
  label  items   perc  new_items  percent   cumprod
0     A      5    NaN   5.000000   1.0000  1.000000
1     B      5   0.00   5.000000   1.0000  1.000000
2     C      5  24.32   6.216000   1.2432  1.243200
3     D      5 -19.57   4.999529   0.8043  0.999906
4     E      5 -91.80   0.409961   0.0820  0.081992
```